# Reading positional file with logstash, converting two string fields to date, applying math operation to another

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

So, I have a positional file that looks like this

```
0100003074400003074400000000103000000000066167424000000000131527492000000000131527463C19860000000000000320160302201603300010019700XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX            000000000133719971                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
02000008013000008013000000001010000000001327506142016033000000000000046053100000000013268252820160516000000000020091000000000066558874002002
```

And I want logstash to ship only the lines starting with '01' to elasticsearch. I've managed to do this by doing the following

```
filter {
    # get only lines that start with 01 

    if ([message] !~ "^01") {
        drop{}
    }

    grok {
          match => { "message" => "^01(?<n_estab>.{9})(?<n_filial>.{9})(?<depart>.{9})(?<prod>.{2})(?<id_apres>.{18})(?<id_mov>.{18})(?<id_mov_orig>.{18})(?<orig_int>.{1})(?<cod_oper>.{1})(?<cod_moeda>.{3})(?<valor>.{14})(?<date_trans>.{8})(?<date_agenda>.{8})(?<num_parcela>.{3})(?<qtd_parcelas>.{3})(?<cod_rub>.{4})(?<desc_rub>.{30})(?<id_pgto>.{18})" } 
    }

    mutate {
        strip => [
          "n_estab",
          "n_filial",
          "depart",
          "prod",
          "id_apres",
          "id_mov",
          "id_mov_orig",
          "orig_int",
          "cod_oper",
          "cod_moeda",
          "valor",
          "date_trans",
          "date_agenda",
          "num_parcela",
          "qtd_parcelas",
          "cod_rub",
          "desc_rub",
          "id_pgto"
        ]
        convert => {
              "n_estab" => "integer"
              "n_filial" => "integer"
              "depart" => "integer"
              "prod"  => "integer"
              "id_apres" => "integer"
              "id_mov" => "integer"
              "id_mov_orig" => "integer"
              "orig_int"  => "string"
              "cod_oper"  => "integer"
              "cod_moeda"  => "integer"
              "valor"  => "float"
              "date_trans" => "string"
              "date_agenda" => "string"
              "num_parcela"  => "integer"
              "qtd_parcelas"  => "integer"
              "cod_rub"  => "integer"
              "desc_rub" => "string"
              "id_pgto" => "integer"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to divide `valor` by 100 and convert fields `date_trans` and `date_agenda` from string to date format, so I can index by any of those fields on elasticsearch and kibana.

I've tried adding the following lines to `filter`

```
ruby { 
    code => "event['valor'] = event['valor'] / 100
        event['date_trans'] = Date.strptime(event['date_trans'], '%Y%m%d')
        event['date_agenda'] = Date.strptime(event['date_agenda'], '%Y%m%d')" 
}
```

After I've added those lines to my conf file, logstash starts, but doesn't parse any of my files... It simply hangs! Since I can add gibberish to the ruby code block and it won't alert me of anything, I figure it must be something with the ruby code, right...?

**UPDATE**

After executing

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/subq_detliq.conf -v --debug --verbose
```

It started inserting into elasticsearch... Does logstash keeps which files it read somewhere and never come back to them?

Also, this it what it's inserting into ES...

```
"message" => "0100001504000001504000000000101000000000063916400000000000124569419000000000124569414C09860000000000011620151127201601260020029700XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX            000000000128479123                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ",
    "@version" => "1",
  "@timestamp" => "2016-04-28T18:11:58.681Z",
        "host" => "cherno-alpha",
        "path" => "/tmp/HSTRD0003/SUBQ_DETLIQ_HSTR_20160124_000100.REM",
     "n_estab" => 15040,
    "n_filial" => 15040,
      "depart" => 1,
        "prod" => 1,
    "id_apres" => 63916400,
      "id_mov" => 124569419,
 "id_mov_orig" => 124569414,
    "orig_int" => "C",
    "cod_oper" => 0,
   "cod_moeda" => 986,
       "valor" => 1.16,
  "date_trans" => #<Date: 2015-11-27 ((2457354j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 "date_agenda" => #<Date: 2016-01-26 ((2457414j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 "num_parcela" => 2,
"qtd_parcelas" => 2,
     "cod_rub" => 9700,
    "desc_rub" => "XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX",
     "id_pgto" => 128479123
```

Somehow Ruby converted the date fields, but not really? ES still thinks it's just a regular string and won't let create an index on them.

Comment: Can you run logstash with the `--debug`  flag and maybe we can get more insights into what's going on?

Comment: That is very weird... When I tried executing with 'service logstash start', it didn't work, it just hangs there, as if there was no new file to read. When I executed '/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f yourconf.conf -v --debug --verbose', it worked... Any idea why?

Comment: Also, Kibana still won't let me index by any of the other time fields, just @timestamp